# Maybe something is wrong with cnosdb's official documentation?

Tags: cnosdb

Here is the statement to create a cnosdb container with docker in the official documentation of cnosdb:

```
  docker run --name cnosdb -p 8902:8902 -d cnosdb/cnosdb:community-latest cnosdb run -M singleton
```

[image]

But when I use the statement as shown in the screenshot, to insert data:

```
curl -i -u "cnosdb:" -H "Accept: application/json" \
-XPOST "http://127.0.0.1:8902/api/v1/sql?db=oceanic_station" \
-d "INSERT INTO air (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, pressure)
VALUES ('2022-10-19 05:40:00', 'XiaoMaiDao', 55, 68, 76), ('2022-10-19 04:40:00',     'XiaoMaiDao', 55, 68, 76);"
```

Docker tells me that the user 'cnosdb' is not found?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the param '--name cnosdb' is to create a container named 'cnosdb',not to create the user name 'cnosdb'.and the official document misread me deeply.

the right param to create user name is '-u cnosdb'.

so did the problem occurred